# Link Realm objects while using Codable

Tags: swift, realm, codable

I want to link Section to my Category model. I am only getting section id in the JSON response so using coder I tried todo like this but didn't work

> Solution below didn't work

```
public required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    self.init()
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
    self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    self.color = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .color) ?? ""
    let sectionId = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .section)
    let section = try! Realm().object(ofType: Section.self, forPrimaryKey: sectionId)
    self.section = section

}
```

> My solution but I dont like the fact it will run a query everytime

```
final class Category : Object, Codable {

@objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var name: String = ""
@objc dynamic var color: String? = ""
@objc dynamic var sectionId: Int = 0
var section: Section? {
    return self.realm?.object(ofType: Section.self, forPrimaryKey: sectionId)
}
```

I am sure there must be a better way of doing it. Any leads appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying you want to have a property of the Category class that is a Section Realm object? Why not just add it as a property `@objc dynamic var my_section: Section?` Then you can remove all of the decode/codable code if it's not needed for anything else.

Comment: @Jay I cant do that because the JSON response doesnt return me proper section object. just an id. and I use do it , it removes all data from my sections table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a lazy variable for the section property the query will only run once. The down side is that if you are observing changes to Category objects you won't get a notification if the corresponding Section object changes.

```
class Category: Object {
    // ...
    @objc dynamic var sectionId: Int = 0

    lazy var section: Section? = {
        return realm?.object(ofType: Section.self, forPrimaryKey: sectionId)
    }()

    override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["section"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I want. In my given situation I dont need to observer changes to section.

Comment: Cool, yeah, I use this strategy all the time.